# Jquery counter and fadein issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Hi I am trying to create a slider that has the circles and counter on the bottom change colors when I rotate the slide. Also, also when I select it, the slider will jump to that slide. I am wondering what is the best way to approach this? Lorempixel.com doesn't show up in code snippet for some reason.

Also, why is my fadein function for right arrow not working correctly? Thanks!

```js
'use strict';

$( document ).ready(function() {


    var total = 11;

    for(var i=1; i < total; i++){
        /*$('#slideshow .pics').append('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/food/'+i+'" />');
        $('#slideshow .pics').append('<b>Slide ' + i + '</b>.'); //add text to slide*/

        $('#slideshow .inner-pics').append('<div class="slide-' + i + '">');
        $('#slideshow .inner-pics div:last').append('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/food/' + i + '" />');
        $('#slideshow .inner-pics div:last').append('<b>Slide ' + i + '</b>.'); //add text to slide
        $('#slideshow .inner-pics').append('</div>');
        $('.circle').append('<i class="fa fa-circle">-</i>');
    }

    var Pictures;

    function slideAnimationLeft(targetLeft) {
        Pictures = $('.inner-pics');

        $(function() {
            Pictures.children('div:first').animate({
                'margin-left': targetLeft + 'px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                Pictures.children('div:first').appendTo(Pictures).css('margin-left', '0px').fadeIn(2000);
            });
        });
    };


    function slideAnimationRight(targetRight) {
        Pictures = $('.inner-pics');

        $(function() {
            Pictures.children('div:first').animate({
                'margin-right': targetRight + 'px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                Pictures.children('div:first').appendTo(Pictures).css('margin-right', '0px').fadeIn(2000);
            });
        });
    };

    $('.left >').click(function() { slideAnimationLeft(-500) } );
    $('.right >').click(function() { slideAnimationRight(500) } );

});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
/* line 6, ../sass/_reset.scss */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
/* line 27, ../sass/_reset.scss */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

/* line 31, ../sass/_reset.scss */
body {
  line-height: 1;
}

/* line 34, ../sass/_reset.scss */
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* line 37, ../sass/_reset.scss */
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

/* line 40, ../sass/_reset.scss */
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

/* line 45, ../sass/_reset.scss */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* line 50, ../sass/_reset.scss */
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* line 6, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
/* line 13, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow > img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
/* line 18, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow .pics {
  z-index: 1;
}
/* line 21, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow .pics div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
/* line 25, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow .pics div b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 30px;
}
/* line 39, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow .inner-pics {
  width: 7000px;
}
/* line 43, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow .control {
  z-index: 2;
}
/* line 47, ../sass/styles.scss */
#slideshow > div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

/* line 55, ../sass/styles.scss */
.circle {
  text-align: center;
}

/* line 61, ../sass/styles.scss */
i.fa-circle {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 2px;
}

/* line 69, ../sass/styles.scss */
i.fa-angle-left {
  margin-top: 20%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* line 77, ../sass/styles.scss */
i.fa-angle-right {
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 87.75%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assignment 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="control">
        <a href="#" class="left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-5x left"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5x right"></i></a>

        <div class="circle">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="pics">
        <div class="inner-pics">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make something like this http://jsfiddle.net/o5ad4gk0/1/

```
var total = 11;
var $pictures = $('.inner-pics');
var delta = 500;
var curent = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < total; i++) {
    $('#slideshow .inner-pics').append('<div class="slide-' + i + '">');
    $('#slideshow .inner-pics div:last').append('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/food/' + i + '" />');
    $('#slideshow .inner-pics div:last').append('<b>Slide ' + i + '</b>'); //add text to slide
    $('#slideshow .inner-pics').append('</div>');
    $('.circle').append('<i class="fa fa-circle">-</i>');
}

function slideAnimationLeft() {
    if(curent<=1) return false;
    curent --;
    $pictures.animate({
        'margin-left': "+="+delta
    }, 1000);
};

function slideAnimationRight() {
    if(curent>=total) return false;
    curent ++;
    $pictures.animate({
        'margin-left': "-="+delta
    }, 1000);
};

$('.left >').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    slideAnimationLeft();
});
$('.right >').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    slideAnimationRight();
});
```